# Ruby concurrency: non-blocking I/O vs threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, eventmachine

I am playing around with concurrency in Ruby (1.9.3-p0), and have created a very simple, I/O-heavy proxy task. First, I tried the non-blocking approach:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/fiber_pool'
require 'em-http'
require 'em-synchrony'
require 'em-synchrony/em-http'

proxy = lambda {|*|
  result = EM::Synchrony.sync EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.com').get
  [200, {}, [result.response]]
}

use Rack::FiberPool, :size => 1000
run proxy

=begin
$ thin -p 3000 -e production -R rack-synchrony.ru start
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)

$ ab -c100 -n100 http://localhost:3000/
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   5.602 seconds
HTML transferred:       21900 bytes
Requests per second:    17.85 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5602.174 [ms] (mean)
=end
```

Hmm, I thought I must be doing something wrong. An average request time of 5.6s for a task where we are mostly waiting for I/O? I tried another one:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/synchrony'
require 'em-synchrony/em-http'

get '/' do
  EM::HttpRequest.new("http://google.com").get.response
end

=begin
$ ruby sinatra-synchrony.rb -p 3000 -e production
== Sinatra/1.3.1 has taken the stage on 3000 for production with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)

$ ab -c100 -n100 http://localhost:3000/
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   5.476 seconds
HTML transferred:       21900 bytes
Requests per second:    18.26 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5475.756 [ms] (mean)
=end
```

Hmm, a little better, but not what I would call a success. Finally, I tried a threaded implementation:

```
require 'rack'
require 'excon'

proxy = lambda {|*|
  result = Excon.get('http://google.com')
  [200, {}, [result.body]]
}    
run proxy

=begin
$ thin -p 3000 -e production -R rack-threaded.ru --threaded --no-epoll start
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)

$ ab -c100 -n100 http://localhost:3000/
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   2.014 seconds
HTML transferred:       21900 bytes
Requests per second:    49.65 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2014.005 [ms] (mean)
=end
```

That was really, really surprising. Am I missing something here? Why is EM performing so badly here? Is there some tuning I need to do? I tried various combinations (Unicorn, several Rainbows configurations, etc), but none of them came even close to the simple, old I/O-blocking threading.

Ideas, comments and - obviously - suggestions for better implementations are very welcome.

Comment: You should not use a distant servers for tests, latency may vary. You should try again the async test with less fibers, with 20 fibers I get 300ms / request versus 1s / request with 1000 fibers using your exact ab line. Your threaded server is using the default eventmachine thread pool which is 20 threads by default.

Comment: Not sure, setting the fiber pool size to 20 actually decreases performance on my box.

Comment: Maybe not 20 but 1000 is really high, I tested with a local server so the response time was really low.

Answer (score 3):

See how your "Time per request" exactly equals total "Time taken for tests"? This is a reporting arithmetic artifact due to your request count (-n) being equal to your concurrency level (-c). The mean-time is the total-time*concurrency/num-requests. So the reported mean when -n == -c will be the time of the longest request. You should conduct your ab runs with -n > -c by several factors to get reasonable measures.

You seem to be using an old version of ab as a relatively current one reports far more detailed results by default.  Running directly against google I show similar total-time == mean time when -n == -c, and get more reasonable numbers when -n > -c. You really want to look at the req/sec, mean across all concurrent requests, and the final service level breakdown to get a better understanding.

```
$ ab -c50 -n50 http://google.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking google.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        gws
Server Hostname:        google.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        219 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   0.023 seconds           <<== note same as below
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      50
Total transferred:      27000 bytes
HTML transferred:       10950 bytes
Requests per second:    2220.05 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       22.522 [ms] (mean)      <<== note same as above
Time per request:       0.450 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1170.73 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    2   0.6      3       3
Processing:     8    9   2.1      9      19
Waiting:        8    9   2.1      9      19
Total:         11   12   2.1     11      22
WARNING: The median and mean for the initial connection time are not within a normal deviation
        These results are probably not that reliable.

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     11
  66%     12
  75%     12
  80%     12
  90%     12
  95%     12
  98%     22
  99%     22
 100%     22 (longest request)        <<== note same as total and mean above


$ ab -c50 -n500 http://google.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking google.com (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:        gws
Server Hostname:        google.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        219 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   0.110 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      500
Total transferred:      270000 bytes
HTML transferred:       109500 bytes
Requests per second:    4554.31 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       10.979 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.220 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2401.69 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        1    1   0.7      1       3
Processing:     8    9   0.7      9      13
Waiting:        8    9   0.7      9      13
Total:          9   10   1.3     10      16

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     10
  66%     11
  75%     11
  80%     12
  90%     12
  95%     13
  98%     14
  99%     15
 100%     16 (longest request)
```